# Is it possible to mix virtual function and function object to work with std algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, polymorphism, functor

For example, there is a bag system:

```
class BagBase
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<BagObj*> ObjVec;
    virtual ObjVec FindObjs(const FinderBase& finder);
protected:
    ObjVec Objs;
}

class Bag1 : public BagBase
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<MyBagObj*> MyObjVec;
    virtual ObjVec FindObjs(const FinderBase& finder);
// ignore ObjVec Objs in BagBase, 
// store objects with another type (with more information)
// but you can still extract BagObj* from MyObjs through FindObjs
private:
    MyObjVec MyObjs;
}

class Bag2 : public BagBase
{
// just use FindObjs defined in BagBase
}
```

And I would like to implement `FindObjs` using `std::find_if`,
For example:

```
struct FinderBase
{
    virtual bool operator()(BagObj* o);
};

struct Finder1 : public FinderBase
{
    virtual bool operator()(BagObj* o);
};

// and Finder2, Finder3, so on, each target to find by different conditions
```

And implement `virtual ObjVec BagBase::FindObjs(const FinderBase& finder);` like:

```
virtual ObjVec BagBase::FindObjs(const FinderBase& finder)
{
    ObjVec results;
    // a while loop execute std::find_if each time
    // below is just a concept
    while (...)
    {
        ObjVec::iterator it = std::find_if(Objs.begin(), Objs.end(), finder);
        if (it != Objs.end())
        {
            results.push_back(*it);
        }
        ++it;
    }
}
```

And because `Bag1` use other kind of vector, it may looks like:

```
virtual ObjVec Bag1::FindObjs(const FinderBase& finder)
{
    ObjVec results;
    while (...)
    {
        // the difference: MyObjVec
        MyObjVec::iterator it = std::find_if(Objs.begin(), Objs.end(), finder);
        if (it != Objs.end())
        {
            // extract Obj* from MyObj*
            MyObj* my_obj = (*it);
            Obj* obj = my_obj->obj;
            results.push_back(obj);
        }
        ++it;
    }
}
```

So the problem is, `std::find_if` copies the `finder`, 
so it doenst know its actual type (it may be `Finder1` or `Finder2`),
it merely copies as though it is a `FinderBase` object.

The `virtual` of `FindObjs` is a must, because there are different kinds of `vector`s, so I cant pass `finder` in using `template`, but this directly contradict with the need of `std::find_if`, which can not deduce the actual type of `finder`.

So what is a better solution of this problem?
Is it possible to mix `virtual` and `template` thing?
Thanks!

P.S. Needs solution of C++03, thanks!

Comment: The main question aside, do you realize that `Bag1` contains two vectors, `Objs` *and* `MyObjs`? Isn't that a waste of space?

Comment: Yes I know, but `Bag1` needs more information with `BagObj`, so there is another `vector`. The original `vector` would be always empty.

Comment: Even an empty vector takes space. You could define an abstract base class that doesn't have any vector at all, and derived classes for the different types of containers.

Comment: btw, you want `std::copy_if` with a `back_inserter`.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `finder` object in a [`reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). [`ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) and `cref` can be used to create one.

```
MyObjVec::iterator it = std::find_if(Objs.begine(), Objs.end(), std::ref(finder));
```

If you're using a pre-C++11 compiler there's [Boost.Ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/ref.html)

EDIT:
 As pointed out in the comments, simply replacing `std::ref` with `boost::ref` doesn't work. This is because `boost::reference_wrapper`, unlike `std::reference_wrapper`, lacks [`operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%28%29). This operator participates in overload resolution only if `std::reference_wrapper` is wrapping a *callable* object, thus allowing it to function transparently as a callable.

To get the same functionality from Boost, we need to use `boost::bind` to allow invoking the callable wrapped in the `boost::reference_wrapper`.

```
MyObjVec::iterator it = std::find_if(Objs.begine(), Objs.end(), 
                                     boost::bind<bool>(boost::ref(finder), _1));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fc30ae06546d68c) showing usage of both `std::ref` and `boost::ref`.

Comment: Got it! I'll try it in Monday and accept your answer later, thanks!

Comment: seems that I cant directly pass `boost::ref(finder)` in, it gives error C2064. Not sure why yet.

Comment: @Marson I wasn't aware of the difference in functionality between the two, see updated answer. Also, I don't know whether the spelling of `begine()` is a typo you made while posting or not, but if it isn't you should consider renaming it to `begin()`. This, aside from being usual convention, will allow your type to be used with [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and range based for loops (both C++11 features)

Comment: ok thanks, I'll check it out and reply here. And yes that `begine` thing is a typo, fixed it now! Sorry for so late reply, I've been busy for other things (from work) and our chinese new year vacation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question at all but here is what I got from reading it.. I'm not sure why `std::ref` or `std::cref` is needed either.. `std::find_if` seems to work fine with polymorphic objects and virtual functions.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Object
{
    void print() {std::cout<<"Object\n";}
    virtual ~Object(){};
};

struct Integer : public Object
{
    void print() {std::cout<<"Integer\n";}
    virtual ~Integer(){}
};

struct Float : public Object
{
    void print() {std::cout<<"Float\n";}
    virtual ~Float(){}
};

struct FinderBase
{
    virtual bool operator()(Object* obj){return obj;}
};

struct Finder : public FinderBase
{
    virtual bool operator()(Object* obj){return obj;}
};

class Parent
{
    protected:
        std::vector<Object*> Objs;

    public:
        Parent() {Objs.push_back(new Object());}
        virtual ~Parent() {delete Objs.back();}

        virtual void find(FinderBase* finder);
};

void Parent::find(FinderBase* finder)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(Objs.begin(), Objs.end(), *finder);
    if (it != Objs.end())
    {
        typename decltype(Objs)::value_type obj = *it;
        obj->print();
    }
}


class Brother : public Parent
{
    protected:
        std::vector<Integer*> Objs;

    public:
        Brother() {Objs.push_back(new Integer());}
        virtual ~Brother() {delete Objs.back();}

        virtual void find(FinderBase* finder);
};

void Brother::find(FinderBase* finder)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(Objs.begin(), Objs.end(), *finder);
    if (it != Objs.end())
    {
        typename decltype(Objs)::value_type b = *it;
        b->print();
    }
}


class Sister : public Parent
{
    protected:
        std::vector<Float*> Objs;

    public:
        Sister() {Objs.push_back(new Float());}
        virtual ~Sister() {delete Objs.back();}

        virtual void find(FinderBase* finder);
};

void Sister::find(FinderBase* finder)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(Objs.begin(), Objs.end(), *finder);
    if (it != Objs.end())
    {
        typename decltype(Objs)::value_type s = *it;
        s->print();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Parent P;
    Brother B;
    Sister S;

    Finder finder;
    P.find(&finder);
    B.find(&finder);
    S.find(&finder);

    std::cout<<"\n\n";

    Parent* ptr = new Parent();
    ptr->find(&finder);
    delete ptr;

    Parent* Bptr = new Brother();
    Bptr->find(&finder);
    delete Bptr;

    Parent* Sptr = new Sister();
    Sptr->find(&finder);
    delete Sptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Object
Integer
Float


Object
Integer
Float
```

You can try it out: http://ideone.com/2zQmT0

Comment: The problematic is that `FinderBase` is polymorphic.

Comment: Well I updated my post. It is the exact same output. Finder is now polymorphic and it works just fine.

Comment: And you have slicing issue... not exposed as `Finder` and `FinderBase` do the exact same thing...

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc612fff88d1ad43) a demo of how slicing's occurring in the OP's example. `foo()` slices the object when passing it to `find_if`, `bar()` obviously doesn't, and `baz()` avoids it by wrapping the object in a `reference_wrapper`.